# Parameter passing from python numpy array to std::vector uint8 array in C++ GNU radio function block

Tags: python, c++, numpy, swig, gnuradio

I am trying to perform frame synchronisation of a "Hello World" message that I transmit over GNU Radio. Initially I add a training sequence before the message and a padding bits before and after the training sequence. This is quite easy to perform in python using numpy array.

```
    s = 'Hello World!\n'
    payload = convert_string_to_10_list(s) #Function to convert string to binary array
    payload_vector=np.array(payload)
    bc13 = np.array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1])
    payload_vector[np.isclose(payload_vector,0)]=-1        
    training = np.hstack((bc13, bc13))
    # concatenate to make our baseband transmitted signal, add some zero pad
    input_vector = np.hstack((np.ones(5)*-1, training, payload_vector, np.ones(5)*-1))
```

When I print it in console, I get the

```
[-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  1.  1. -1. -1.  1. -1.  1. -1.
 -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  1.  1. -1. -1.  1. -1.  1. -1. -1.  1. -1. -1.  1.
 -1. -1. -1. -1.  1.  1. -1. -1.  1. -1.  1. -1.  1.  1. -1.  1.  1. -1.
 -1. -1.  1.  1. -1.  1.  1. -1. -1. -1.  1.  1. -1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.
 -1.  1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  1. -1.  1. -1.  1.  1.  1. -1.  1.  1.
 -1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.  1.  1.  1. -1. -1.  1. -1. -1.  1.  1. -1.  1.
  1. -1. -1. -1.  1.  1. -1. -1.  1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  1. -1. -1. -1. -1.
  1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  1. -1.  1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
```

But now I need to send it to vector source available in GNU radio. The function available in python is

```
self.input_vector_source = blocks.vector_source_b(input_vector, True, len(input_vector), [])
```

When I run my script I get type mismatch error (at,least that is what I assume). The error displayed is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./frame_sync_sim.py", line 74, in <module>
    tb = top_block()
  File "./frame_sync_sim.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.input_vector_source = blocks.vector_source_b(input_vector, True, len(input_vector), [])          
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/blocks/blocks_swig1.py", line 5307, in make
    return _blocks_swig1.vector_source_b_make(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: in method 'vector_source_b_make', argument 1 of type 'std::vector< std::uint8_t,std::allocator< std::uint8_t > > const &'
```

How do I pass the numpy array to GNU radio vector source function. The data bits are in bipolar format. Is that causing any problem?

Comment: The decimal points indicate an array of float, not an array of int, which would be compatible with vector<uint8_t>

Comment: yep, `np.ones` creates a float matrix. You'll want to convert the `input_vector` using `.to(np.uint8)` or similar